# Set the default Google Analytics authentication in R

Tags: r, google-analytics

I am using the R packages `googleAnalyticsR` and `googleAuthR` to connect to GA and get data from it. However, every time, I run the function `ga_auth()` it open a web windows and ask me to verify my account. This is not convenient for someone else to use my account. I am think that whether or not there is a way I can set up my account email and account password in some R function, so that it won't ask someone else about my credentials. BTW, I don't want to use client_id and client_secret but only my GA account email and password. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: So you want to store your username and password so anyone can use it? That seems very insecure. The whole point of authentication is for someone to login to verify they have access to a resource. This seems dangerous.

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, that is what I want. is there a way to do it? Since it is only for internal use, only my collages can see my credentials

Answer (score 0):

When you run `ga_auth()` it will create a cache file in the same directory (called `ga.oauth` in the latest 0.5.0 version, `.httr-oauth` in the earlier versions)

If you make that file available to your work collegeus, then they can use your credentials, without needing to provide their own and go through the authentication flow.

You can either send them a copy of the `ga.oauth`file or rename it and then tell it to be used by passing it in the first argument e.g. `ga_auth("my_custom_file.oauth")`

If you would like it to be more hassle free, if you have access to the system the users will be using, then setup an environment argument that points to the custom cache file.  You can achieve this using the `.Renviron` file that is placed in the user's home directory.  Then set the path to the authentication file to the `GA_AUTH_FILE` argument, e.g.

`GA_AUTH_FILE="/Users/mark/dev/auth/ga.oauth"`

Once that is setup, then when you load the library e.g. `library(googleAnalyticsR)` it will auto-authenticate with that auth file.

There are some more details on that in the [setup section of the googleAnalyticsR website](http://code.markedmondson.me/googleAnalyticsR/setup.html).